# Coloring shell command and output differrently

Tags: bash, colors, prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Customizing bash shell: Bold/color the command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/customizing-bash-shell-bold-color-the-command)

```
bash $ cat what-i-want
"I want the output be in a different color."
```

I'd like my commands stand out among the output, without making the prompt overly long. I want to see commands and output in different colors. I understand how to manipulate prompt colors by setting `PS1`.

Is there a way to change color after I pressed `Enter` but before the command started executing?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20803/9537)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the `bind` command of `bash` / `readline` to do something on `Enter` (I believe I have seen it mentioned on this site recently, but I'm unable to find it atm).

Another option is creating an alias, you would prepend in front of the command:

```
$ alias x='echo <ANSI ESCAPE>;'
$ x cat what-you-want
```

As Kevin pointed out, remember to reset the colour at the beginning of your prompt.

Comment: You'd have to add a color reset escape to the beginning of the prompt.

Comment: Regarding “do something on Enter” – note that 1) Enter not always executes the command; 2) not always Enter executes the command.