# Unix - can i make the command line readable?

Tags: command-line, terminal, colors, prompt

Let's say I have this commandline:

```
~/development/company/folder:
```

and i run this command

```
./gradlew appRun
```

then my command line looks like this:

```
~/development/company/folder: ./gradlew appRun
```

Now, if there is an error and there is a bunch of output, then i need to scroll up and, because unix just formats everything the same, it's real easy to get all the lines and commands mixed up.

What I would like is for each command I enter to be like, bright red or bold or something, and all the output from that to be white or whatever it currently is.

How do i do that?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/customizing-bash-shell-bold-color-the-command, for bash

Comment: @Jeff yeh, this is a duplicate

Comment: It is a quite different answer for the Z shell, note.

Comment: Try [`liquidprompt`](https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt), it only changes the prompts, but the changed  prompts are conspicuous that a command's output is usually distinct from its invocation.

Answer (score -1):

It's not that UNIX formats everything the same.
Any command you run can also write formatted output.

When you run for instance `./gradlew appRun`, just redirect the output (both the error stream and the standard output stream to a file)

```
./gradlew appRun &> mylogfile.log
```

Comment: Question: How do I find the needles in my haystack?  Answer: Here’s a tool that will move all your hay to another farm, leaving the needles behind. Then you’ll have no trouble seeing the needles, as they’ll be the only things there. (Of course you’ll have to go to the other farm to look at the hay.)    :-(    ⁠